# Ruby get instance method definition from Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get definition of method :foo from Class object.

```
class Bar
  def foo(required_name, optional="something")
    puts "Hello args are #{required_name}, #{optional}"
  end

  def self.bar
    puts "I am easy, since I am static"
  end
end
```

I *cannot create instance* of class since I need method definition to evaluate should I create object (app requirments).  `Bar.class.???(:foo)`

I can get with `bar` definition with `Bar.class.method(:bar)` but of course I need `foo`, thanks!

UPDATE:

Using **Ruby 1.8.7**

Comment: What do you mean, you need to run an instance method from outside an instance before you decide if you should create an object?!?! This seems fundamentally broken.

Comment: I inherited the code (as always) which will delegate method invocation. Delegation happens in static class which than is passed to Thor framework to create instance and run task (method). Thor framework does good job of this but due to some customer specific request there were "upgrades" to logic to support what Thor cannot. So before passing task I need to see if required parameters have been met or Thor will not behave properly.

More work would be needed to re factor all properly include monkey patches to Thor, hope it makes at least a little sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the method `instance_method` on a class like this :

```
Bar.instance_method(:foo)
```

which will return an instance of `UnboundMethod`. (See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/UnboundMethod.html)

Comment: Oh and by the way, `Bar.class` will return `Class`, you should use just `Bar.*[methods]*`.

Comment: This works great but I have updated the question, I am using 1.8.7 and there `UnboundMethod` does not have parameters mutator. I am trying to get Method definition in this case parameter list. If there is no better answers I will accept this since is close enough.

Comment: >> Joe.instance_method(:say).arity
=> 1, will tell you the number of parameters to a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can discover if the class has an instance method `:foo` like so:

```
Bar.instance_methods.include? :foo
```

An example:

```
String.instance_methods.include? :reverse
=> true
String.instance_methods.include? :each
=> false
```